# flask-sqlalchemy model class derivation without join

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a class inheritence between my model objects just for sake of code clarity, as I have 4 models that contain similar columns except for one.

Can I simply inherit my db.model class and add a _*tablename_* or will it necessarily create a join relation between base class and children? I don't want any join here, just keep the code clean and not copy pasted... Should I use the sqlalchemy 'Base' class for my base class?

Comment: Review https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html#composing-mapped-hierarchies-with-mixins and perhaps https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_config.html#abstract

Comment: Got to say these SqlAlchemy docs are a bit overwhelming... Just wanted some neat code, not a course in mixins ;)